# Gravity Forms data to SOAP Service says Could not connect to host

Tags: wordpress, soap, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to send some selected fields of a gravity form to a soap service whenever a user/visitor submits form

This is the soap markup the service provider gave me:

Web Raw Details

```
POST http://192.168.1.20:443/callpack.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/callbalance"
Content-Length: 443
Host: 192.168.1.20:443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tem:callpack>
<tem:username>root</tem:username>
<tem:password>admin123</tem:password>
<tem:sendernum>18002264180</tem:sendernum>
<tem:receivernum>18007264316</tem:receivernum>
<tem:unitId>pack_1_55972</tem:unitId>
<tem:minutes>70</tem:minutes>
</tem:callpack>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

////**UPDATE**////

After reading around i finally modified my code to the below but now when you submit a form it says **Could not connect yo host**

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

$location = 'http://192.168.1.20:443/callpack.asmx?wsdl'; 

$params = array(
    'username' => "root",
    'Password' => "admin_123",
    'mainnum' => "18002264180",
    'receivernum'  => $entry["1"],
    'unitId'    => "pack_1_55972",
    'minutes'   => $entry["15"],
);


$options = array(
  'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
  'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
  'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(
    array(
      'ssl'=> array(
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
        'ciphers' => 'SHA256',
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false, 
        'allow_self_signed' => true
      )
    )
  )
);

try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($location, $options);
    $data = $soap->callpack($params);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

print_r($data);
}
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

try adding semicolons instead of commas to the following lines:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "admin_123";
$mainnum = "18006318990";
$random_num = rand(1000,9999);
```

Comment: Please i've update the question